# Transform XML to XML with XSLT with conditions

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I need transform some xml to another, using XSLT.

The input looks like this:

```
 <RootNode>
<Products>
    <Price>10.02</Price>
    <TaxRate>1.23</TaxRate>
    <CurrencyId>USD</CurrencyId>
</Products>
</RootNode>
```

and the output:

```
    <RootNode>
<Products> 
    <Product>
        <Prices>
            <Price>10.02</Price>
            <TaxRate type="0">16</TaxRate>
            <Currency>USD</Currency>
        </Prices>
    </Product>
</Products> 
</RootNode>
```

For now I'm trying something like this, but this not working:

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <RootElement>
        <xsl:for-each select="Supplier-Catalog/Products">
            <xsl:attribute-set name="Price" use-attribute-sets="Prices">
                <xsl:value-of select="Price" />
            </xsl:attribute-set>
         </xsl:for-each>
    </RootElement>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

TaxRate type="0" - depends on value of TaxRate from the input.

Can someone help me with this ?

**EDIT**

ok, i created something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <RootElement>
        <xsl:for-each select="Supplier-Catalog/Products">
            <Prices>
                <Price>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Price" />
                </Price>
                <TaxRate>
                    <xsl:value-of select="TaxRate" />
                </TaxRate>
                <Currency>
                    <xsl:value-of select="CurrencyId" />
                </Currency>
            </Prices>
         </xsl:for-each>
    </RootElement>
</xsl:template>
```

and this is ok, but still don't know how to to add "type=0" to the TaxRate attribute

**EDIT 2**

One more question...

For this structure

```
    Products>
    <Stock>
        <Quantity>5</Quantity>
    </Stock>
    <Stock>
        <Quantity>50</Quantity>
    </Stock>
</Products><Products>
    <Stock>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    </Stock>
    <Stock>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    </Stock>
</Products>
```

and this XSLT

```
<xsl:for-each select="Products">
            <Product>
                <Stock>
                    <Quantity>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(//Products/Stock/Quantity)" />
                    </Quantity>
                </Stock>
            </Product>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </Products>
```

I get this:

```
<Products>    
<Product>
 <Stock>
    <Quantity>58</Quantity>
 </Stock>
</Product>
<Product>
  <Stock>
    <Quantity>58</Quantity>
 </Stock>
</Product>
```

This is wrong, because it sum all the values, not:

```
<Products>    
<Product>
 <Stock>
    <Quantity>55</Quantity>
 </Stock>
</Product>
<Product>
  <Stock>
    <Quantity>3</Quantity>
 </Stock>
</Product>
```

Where, I make a mistake ?

Comment: Can you explain the logic for the TaxRate type. If it is not always 0, what are the rules that determine its value? Thanks

Comment: You can literally write the attribute with e.g. `<TaxRate type="0"><xsl:value-of select="TaxRate"/></TaxRate>`, but as Tim says, depending on your logic to compute the value you might need to do it a bit differently..

Comment: 1.23 =0 and value 16, 0.7 = 1 and value 3

Comment: Will TaxRate only ever contain "1.23" or "0.7" then, or can it contain other values?

Comment: 1.23, 0.7 and 0. Only this three values are possible

Comment: In sum function you need to do like: <xsl:value-of select="sum(Stock/Quantity)" />

Comment: see this: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBth/27

Comment: due to for each you already on products node, so you need to take all quantity inside that particular products.

Comment: Ok, thanks, my stupid mistake;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go with choose/when condition while creating attribute and assigning the value like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <RootElement>
            <xsl:for-each select="RootNode/Products">
                <Prices>
                    <Price>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Price" />
                    </Price>
                    <TaxRate>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="TaxRate=1.23">
                                <xsl:attribute name="type"><xsl:value-of select="0"/></xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:value-of select="'16'"/>
                            </xsl:when>

                            <xsl:when test="TaxRate=0.7">
                                <xsl:attribute name="type"><xsl:value-of select="1"/></xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:value-of select="'3'"/>
                            </xsl:when>

                            <xsl:when test="TaxRate=0">
                                <xsl:attribute name="type"><xsl:value-of select="0"/></xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:value-of select="'0'"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </TaxRate>
                    <Currency>
                        <xsl:value-of select="CurrencyId" />
                    </Currency>
                </Prices>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </RootElement>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Check this link for the reference: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBth/26

Comment: Thanks everyone for help :)